# PostGIS spatial reference ID (SRID) for regular cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, epsg, srid

I would like to store a polygon as a set of 2D points represented as x, y coordinates of a Cartesian coordinate system.

Which spatial reference can I use? Looking at my spatial_ref_sys table, all the spatial references seem to be geography related.

The points of the polygon would represent satellite measurements which I would invoke `ST_ConvexHull` on to get the shape of the satellite footprint.

Comment: You could just keep the srid as -1.

Comment: Are you sure I could **store** points with an invalid SRID? I don't think that the `ST_ConvexHull` function would work.

Comment: I have just tested with a layer having srid=-1, and ST_ConvexHull can be used without any issues.

Answer (score 4):

If you do no reprojection with the data, it does not really matter what projected CRS you are using.

You can use EPSG:3857 (Google Mercator), if your data does not exceed the bounds of

```
-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34
```

(Not sure what happens if the data is outside those bounds)

Comment: Yes, I ended up deciding to use something like this, only I chose EPSG:3395 (World Mercator). Any reason why I should prefer Google Mercator? My positions are in the range -250000 to 250000, so I should be safe.

Comment: EPSG:3395 should do as well.