# Strip SRID from PostGIS geometries

Tags: postgis

**Short version**

How can I remove SRID information from PostGIS geometry? Is `ST_SetSRID(geom, 0)` well-defined?

**Long version**

I am rendering maps, using PostGIS. To do this, I create a temporary table, and populate it by `ST_Transform()`:ing my geometries from EPSG:4326 to my desired map projection (usually EPSG:3006, SWEREF99TM) and using `ST_Affine()` to scale and translate them into map coordinates (90-per-inch units on the paper). I then do some processing on this temporary table (cartographic generalization of different kinds), before marshalling it all out to the styling stage.

Apparently, the result of `ST_Affine(ST_Transform(..., srid), ...)` is considered to be “in” that SRID, even though the `ST_Affine` makes this dubious, at best. This means that whenever I want to add geometry from other sources into the mix, that, too, has to be tagged with that SRID, even though it is actually in “paper space”. This means that I have to keep track of the SRID in various places in my program, which are really only concerned with things like “25 mm from the left side of the paper”. If I don’t, PostGIS complains that I am doing
operations on geometries with different SRID:s.

It seems like PostGIS happily performs things like `ST_Intersects` on geometries with no SRID, so if I could get everything to this state, I would be fine.

Comment: You can't eliminate a fundamental property of the `geometry` type. I'd suggest doing all your geometric processing in the projection before doing the Affine transformation (and doing a `SetSRID` to zero afterward).

Comment: It should be OK to use SRID=0 even it might be more correct to use SRID=-1. This is from the GeoPackage standard but same should apply to PostGIS `The record with an srs_id of -1 SHALL be used for undefined Cartesian coordinate reference systems. The record with an srs_id of 0 SHALL be used for undefined geographic coordinate reference systems.` See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64252/postgis-spatial-reference-id-srid-for-regular-cartesian-coordinate-system.